# CGI - How does Kerberos Single Sign On work

Tags: cgi, kerberos

I have a question regarding CGI applications and Kerberos authentication.
I know, that a webserver, like apache, can authenticate a user against `Active Directory` and Kerberos, and I also know that I can do this on my own, if a user sends the `username & password` combination.

But how would I implement a `Single Sign On` on my own?
Kerberos gives you a `Ticket Granting Ticket` if I understand it correctly, but how do I obtain it in the CGI environment?
I tried for example listing the whole environment variables apache provides and also the data transmitted via `POST` request, nothing useful showed up.

Is this possible at all, or do I have to rely on the webserver?

This question is not programming language specific, it just asks whether I can obtain the ticket granting ticket in the CGI environment.

Thanks for any insight!